# Represent array with indices using dot record nodes (Graphviz)

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm using Graphviz to represent arrays, using `subgraphs` and `record` nodes:

```
subgraph cluster_array
{
    label="my array"
    Array [shape="record", label="A | B | C | D"]
    Array
}
```

I would like to add *external* indices for each array elements, mapping `0 -> A`, `1 -> B` and so on.

I want to achieve a result similar to:

[image]

I've searched online and tried using `xlabel` but couldn't find a way to correctly add a label for each record element. I've also tried making the indices part of the label, and moving the label with `lp`, but it seems to have no effect on `record` nodes.

**Is it possible to add external element labels to `record` nodes using GraphViz?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a real answer to your question (which, I think, would be "no") but a workaround that may give you what you want. I use a "parallel" record node with no borders (or paper color borders, to be exact), located very close and connected by an invisible edge:

```
digraph so
{
    subgraph cluster0
    {
        rank = same{ Array notes }
        color = white;
        Array [ shape = record, label = "{ A | B | C | D }"] ;
        notes [ shape = record, color = white, label = "{ a_1 | b_2 | c_3 | d_4 }" ];
        Array -> notes[ style = invis ];
    }
    nodesep = .0;
    X -> Array -> Z;
}
```

which yields

[image]